# WebView2 ExecuteScriptAsync with XML input

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xml, webview2

I want to run a C# function using `ExecuteScriptAsync()` with XML text as input.

Something like that:

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 16\" standalone=\"no\" ?><values>42</values>";
webView2Control.CoreWebView2.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/erezf/AppData/Local/Temp/index.html");
var input = "func(" + xml + ")";
await webView2Control.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(input);
```

The HTML file includes the function `func`:

```
<script id="test" type="text/javascript">
    function func(xml) { alert(xml); }
</script>
```

This code doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML string being passed to the Javascript function is missing single or double quotes.
If you look at the input variable in the debugger, it will look like:

```
func(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 16" standalone="no" ?><values>42</values>)
```

Simply add single quotes like this:

```
var xml = "'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 16\" standalone=\"no\" ?><values>42</values>'";
```

Comment: ok thanks, for this simple case it works but my real xml is much bigger and it doesn't work.
The real xml contains also this values: "89.356984\n55.000000"
I can't put it here because it is too long.
Is there any problem with the \n character in the ExecuteScriptAsync?

Comment: ok, I fixed it!
The \n need to be replaced with \\n:
xml = xml.Replace("\n", "\\n");

now it works :)

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution was:

```
1. add ' ' in the " ".
2. replace the "\n" with "\\n".
```